# how do I upload video music to my website with html or python?

Tags: python, html

How can I upload music videos to my website, so whenever a users logs in they can see the music videos that I have uploaded.

I have done some research and found `YouTube API` but I cannot use that.
Any other solutions are welcome.

Comment: The answer to your question is YES, someone know how to do it. Read this please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I'll keep it in my mind for the next time

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upload music videos to your website using HTML.

The source element can be used along with the audio or video element to specify more than one file format. When more than one format is provided, the browser selects the format best suited to the visitor’s device. When the source element is used, it replaces the **src** attribute.By providing multiple formats, you increase the chances that every visitor to your site will be able to view or listen to the media content on your site.Refer [1] for more details.

The three most important attributes that you must mention in your code will be src, controls and type.

You can follow the below HTML code to upload your music videos,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Video</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <video controls>
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

Regards,

Pooja S

[1] https://html.com/media/

Comment: I got it now. Thank you so much Pooja S!!